# Who exactly came out of Pandora's box?

Tags: code-breaker

I vaguely remember the manga saying it was the Emperor that came out. So then my following questions is why won't they reveal what the Emperor truly looks like?

Also, how can there be two separate Emperors - one from Pandora's box and Chibi Emperor following Ogami around? Shouldn't they merge?

Who exactly did Pandora's box produce?